# Regression using proportions of Likert-type responses to questions as predictors for a continuous variable

Tags: regression, ordinal-data, likert

Suppose I have data from customer surveys. It is Likert-like, but individual responses are not available. Results are given as proportions of total responses to each question. The count of responses to each question is available, if needed.

I need to create a regression model with a continuous “returns rate” as the dependent variable and the results for each question as independent variables. The goal is to determine which questions have the greatest impact on the returns rate, as well as use the results of the survey to predict the returns rate for a given year.

I understand that Likert scales generally shouldn’t be treated as continuous or equally spaced. Rather, they are ordinal. The main complication here is that I only have the percentage of responses in each Likert category, not the individual responses themselves.

There are several techniques I’ve researched, including logit regression and monotonic effects (R package brms). I was unable to determine how to correctly use them for this specific type of data.
Which regression technique would be most appropriate for this data, and what are some tips on how to structure/implement the model?

The following is an example that illustrates the type of data I’m working with:

| 2022 |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | Strongly agree | Somewhat agree | Indifferent | Somewhat disagree | Strongly disagree |
| I am satisfied with the product quality. | 27% | 37% | 3% | 21% | 11% |
| I consider the price to be fair. | 27% | 36% | 0% | 0% | 38% |
| I am satisfied with the service. | 29% | 7% | 12% | 29% | 23% |
| I believe the return policy is fair. | 52% | 14% | 0% | 15% | 20% |

| 2021 |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | Strongly agree | Somewhat agree | Indifferent | Somewhat disagree | Strongly disagree |
| I am satisfied with the product quality. | 33% | 41% | 8% | 13% | 5% |
| I consider the price to be fair. | 21% | 34% | 12% | 14% | 19% |
| I am satisfied with the service. | 25% | 19% | 16% | 25% | 15% |
| I believe the return policy is fair. | 51% | 19% | 4% | 15% | 10% |

| 2020 |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | Strongly agree | Somewhat agree | Indifferent | Somewhat disagree | Strongly disagree |
| I am satisfied with the product quality. | 38% | 52% | 2% | 2% | 7% |
| I consider the price to be fair. | 16% | 27% | 24% | 15% | 18% |
| I am satisfied with the service. | 26% | 18% | 19% | 26% | 11% |
| I believe the return policy is fair. | 49% | 21% | 0% | 18% | 12% |

|  | Returns rate |
| --- | --- |
| 2022 | 12.30% |
| 2021 | 13.50% |
| 2020 | 11.90% |

Comment: What are you trying to find out?  What are your research questions?